# Multipart Request with Custom DTO using Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest

Below is my Rest api which accepts a multipart file and a custom dto

```
@RequestMapping(path="/manual", method = RequestMethod.POST) 
public ResponseEntity<?> createObject(@RequestPart CustomDTO dto, @RequestPart(name = "file", required = true) MultipartFile file) { 

    //Some code here

}
```

Following is a `CustomDTO`

```
public class CustomDTO implements Serializable { 

// Few attributes and its respective getters and setter are there

}
```

Now on making a request it gives me an error as below
[image]

But if in rest api instead of `CustomDTO` if I make the data type as String then it works properly and then using objectmapper I am able to convert it to `CustomDTO`.
But please help me out on how to directly accept it as `CustomDTO` and not String.

**Note:** Am using Spring Boot

Answer (score 0):

try below one.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/manual", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<?> createObject( @Valid CustomDTO dto, @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file ) {
        //
}
```